# Get module name of class object which module is __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a base class `Base` that is in module `base.py`.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__module__)
```

Also, there is a child class `Child` that is in module `child.py`.

```
from test.base import Base

class Child(Base):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Child()
```

I run `python child.py`.
I want statement `print(self.__module__)` to print `child` or `child.py`, not `__main__` as it is currently printed.

P.S. Without redefining **init** method in child class

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting functionality directly in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, define a `main` function. Then, in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, *import the `main` function* from the `child` module and run that version:

```
import test.base

class Child(test.base.Base):
    pass

def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Even though this is child.py, it's not the child module.
    # Import main from the child module so we get the right Child class.
    import child
    child.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm not sure what you really mean.
But i think `isinstance()` will help you.

In the__init__of Base class:

```
if isinstance(obj, Child):
    self.__module__ = "Child"
```

or just use `self.__class__`

Comment: it's not that I mean. If I have complex `mro` with many classes, I need to write such many `if isinstance` as I have classes?

Comment: try  `self.__class__` ?

Answer (score 0):

`__file__` will contain 'child.py' for you.

```
print(__file__)
```